# Idiom for "I came, I saw, I ate" (or drank)

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

I'm trying to follow the "ee" sound pattern at the end of each word in the idiom "veni, vidi, vici" with translations of the following:

I came, I saw, I ate: *Veni, Vidi, Edi*

I came, I saw, I drank: *Veni, Vidi, Bibi*

How much have I butchered these words? :) I'm trying to stick to the sound patterns, but also not flagrantly violate the Latin grammar.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your answers are fine: confirm it [here](https://www.latin-is-simple.com/en/vocabulary/verb/3543/)

For very enthusiastic eating and drinking you could try

> [vŏro, āvi, ātum,](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.20:1351.lewisandshort) 1, v. a. and n. Sanscr. root gar-, to swallow; Gr. root βορ- in βιβρώσκω, to devour; cf. also gramen,
>
> to swallow whole, swallow up, eat greedily, devour (cf. absorbeo).

*Veni, Vidi, Voravi.*

Comment: Thanks for that link - very useful!

Comment: +1 for the consonance!