# What is Latin for Devour?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know nothing of latin. Just think these words sound cool and could be a good name for the game I've been working on. The game is all about devouring resources to make yourself stronger. You eventually leave the planet void of any resources so I figured devour would be a good concept to go off of

Initial googling showed me that it's Devorandum which sounds cool but other sources are telling me that means food

Comment: Welcome to the site! Did you want the word to be from the perspective of the person doing the devouring, or are you telling someone that they should devour stuff? For a good first-person "I devour" example, see this post on translating [I came, I saw, I ate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/idiom-for-i-came-i-saw-i-ate-or-drank/12521#12521).

Answer (score 5):

The Latin word for “devour” is *devorare* or *vorare*. Of these, *devorare* is obviously the root of English “devour.” It is formed from the base *vorare* and the intensifier prefix *de-*, which indicates a completeness of action, but as *vorare* already means “to swallow whole, swallow up,” I honestly do not see much difference in meaning between the two.

*Devorandum* is a form that can mean a number of things depending on context, and without context it does not mean much. (And certainly not “food,” although “that which is to be devoured” is within range – which, by the way, only sounds so weird because English has no comparable form.) For example, you may have heard the famous quote:

> Nunc est bibendum.
> *Now let us drink.*

⋯ which was actually written by Horace, a very famous Roman poet, in the late first century BC ([Carmen 1,37](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Carmina_(Horatius)/Liber_I/Carmen_XXXVII)). (What was Horace so happy about? The death of Cleopatra.) By analogy you can form:

> Nunc est devorandum.
> *Now let us devour.*

Unfortunately that does not make much sense even in English. When we say “now let us drink,” we can imagine what we're supposed to drink—alcohol—and apart from that, drinking is a social activity independent of the exact substance we pour down. Not so with devouring, obviously. The exhortation “let us devour” would only prompt confused stares and the question: devour what? and why?

For your game, I would suggest an imperative. That could be:

- *Devora* or *vora* (addressed at one person)
- *Devorate* or *vorate* (addressed at multiple people)

(There is also a so-called “future imperative,” which is used for laws and general precepts. You may have heard of the boy scout motto *Estote parati*; in the same vein you could say: *Voratote*. At that point we're in distinctly weird territory though, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 3):

I would play on the theme of the well-known expressions, like 'casus vorandi', or smth like this, based on the verb forms of state.

Comment: I've never heard the expression "casus vorandi" before...could you clarify what it means?

Comment: Oh, it is follow famous expression 'casus belli', but for the case of the author's synopsis, where something happened to need to devour any piece of the found resource.

Comment: If we're going down that road, why not: *Voro, ergo sum*? 

Answer (score 2):

Manducus, -i

This is a term from Roman street theatre. *'Manducare'* means to chew,  and the manducus appears to have worn a mask which chewed and slobbered, part mime, part puppetry. This is a non-speaking part, and as a result there is lots of [conjecture and misinformation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atellan_Farce)

Ainsworth 1753:
***Manducus, -i*** m. *A bugbear, or hobgoblin, dressed up in a terrible shape, with wide jaws and great teeth granching, shown at plays.* Si recte saltem interpretur *Festus* locum *Plautinum.*
"Quid si aliquo ad ludos pro manduco locem?" *Rud.* 2.6.51

For comparison: [Lewis and Short: manducus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?q=manducus)

Comment: I think you misread the question for *one who devours*, but I think the person meant the verb, for which I actually prefer your own previous suggestion in the linked thread (in Adam's comment under the question).